# Reusing a render target to create multiple Texture2D's (XNA)

Tags: xna, textures, xna-4.0

i want to be able to loop through a hole bunch of textures, and render them on an object. I then want the rendered image to be placed onto a texture2D.

The point? well hopefully i will end up with an array of Texture2D's containing a model with multiple skins.

Here's my code:

```
        for (byte i = 1; i < allBlockIso.Count(); i++)
        {
            DisplayBox.SetValue(i);
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(cubeTarget);
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            DrawIsoCube();
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
            allBlockIso[i] = (Texture2D)cubeTarget;
        }
```

DisplayBox.SetValue is a function which goes through and sets the texture. This is working! DrawIsoCube() draws the cube (the test model) and this is working too.
The problem is definitely something to do with the unreusability of the render target.

Pretty simple yet it's not working. It appears that whatever the last image being rendered is, is shown in every image of the allBlockIso array.

Anyone know a fix?
Cheers.

P.S. sorry if this wan't explained well. I'm not very good at explaining :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `RenderTarget2D` is also a `Texture2D`. You don't ever "convert" it to a texture - it simply already *is* a texture. So you're simply passing the one object around and reusing it.

(You can prove this in the Debugger by giving the object a marker - you will see that every texture in your array is the *same* object!)

So you have two options:

- You could create multiple `RenderTarget2D` objects and use one for each texture.
- You could create multiple `Texture2D` objects, and copy your render target into a texture, using the `GetData` and `SetData` functions, after each time you render to it. (Your data will have to go through (copied into and then copied out of) a buffer, which you *can* reuse because it is not used in the final result.)

If you are doing this while your game is running (it is happening each frame or frequently), you should probably use the first approach. If you are doing this at load time (it happens once or occasionally), then you should probably use the second approach.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509265/after-writing-to-a-rendertarget-how-to-efficiently-clone-the-output).

Also look into the difference between [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) and [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) (see [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx) for *lots* of information about the .NET type system). `Texture2D` is a reference type, which means that the variable you hold is a *reference* to the object - not the object itself.

Comment: +1. And from Master Hargreaves :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/26/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx
See the similarity in his first example? :)